# Vue JS text interpolation expression returning html or component

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

How can I render a component inside a template using text interpolation? I tried the following code:

```
<template>
   <div> {{ booleanValue ? "<my-component />" : "Some Text" }} </div>
</template>
```

But this is printing the actual code with the "double mustaches", removing the component tag and also rendering the component.

```
{{ booleanValue ? "" : "Some Text" }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I still don't know how to do it with text interpolation, but I found a simpler way to this: [Conditional Rendering](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/conditional.html)

```
 <div v-if="booleanValue"> 
    <my-component /> 
 </div>
 <div v-else>Some Text</div>
```

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. Text interpolation is - wait for it - text only. No components.